# difference - availability and available in a sentence

Tags: american-english, british-english

I am answering someone at work who asked me what availability do I have over the next few weeks, in order to see if I could be assigned a task. Which is the following two forms is correct and why?

- I may have up to 20% availability in the coming weeks.
- I may be available 20% of the time in the coming weeks.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: (a) may be grammatical, but sounds more than faintly ridiculous. I'd used a hedged (b): 'I think I'll be available about 20% of the time over the next few weeks.'

Comment: As we determined in your previous question, you had it right the first time around. Just how much time are you willing to spend on massaging a completely inconsequential sentence and making it only worse in ever new ways. It was fine to begin with. Stop wasting your life time away.

Comment: 20% of what? Just say: *I have about x hours per week of availability in the coming weeks.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Both are grammatically correct.**

The first has an air of "business-speak" about it, sounding more convoluted than it needs to be. The second is simpler and clearer, which I would personally consider to be a good thing.